# Duplicate html code in a email template without messing up the format

Tags: html, email

I am doing my first email template and I have a question. In the body of the email template there is a section with an image and a description (deal). I want to be able to duplicate this code to have as many deals as I need without messing up the frames design. When I did the design in photoshop I made it for 2 deals. But when I copy and paste the same code to make a third one I riun the design. I know it has something to do with the height of the frames I am using, but I haven´t been able to resolve this. Photoshop generated some spaces using spacer.gif with aditional code (at the end of the html code). If I delete that the design falls apart. WHat can I do?

Thank you,

Juan.

Here is the example of the html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>email</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table width="680" height="900" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Table_01">
    <tr>
        <td width="13" height="900" rowspan="11" bgcolor="#3b64aa">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="654" height="9" colspan="5" bgcolor="#3b64aa"></td>
        <td width="13" height="900" rowspan="11" bgcolor="#3b64aa">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="212" height="89" colspan="2" bgcolor="#32322b">
          <img src="images/logo.png" width="212" height="89" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="370" height="89" bgcolor="#32322b" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14pt; color:#FFFFFF; vertical-align:middle; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" >Deals</td>
        <td width="72" height="89" colspan="2" bgcolor="#32322b">
      <img src="images/cupon.png" width="72" height="89" alt="" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="12" height="590" rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="630" height="17" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="12" height="590" rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="630" height="130" colspan="3">
        <img src="images/Template-Email-kuponkis_10.jpg" width="630" height="130" alt="" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="630" height="155" colspan="3" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;" ><p><strong>Nombre de la promoción</strong></p>
        <p>nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nunc.</p>
        <p>Oferta valida desde <strong style="color:#1f52aa">Mar 1 de 2013</strong> hasta <strong style="color:#1f52aa">Junio 10 de 2013</strong></p>
        <p> <del>$1.000.000</del><strong style="color:#1f52aa; font-size:18px"> $800.000</strong></p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="630" height="130" colspan="3">
        <img src="images/Template-Email-kuponkis_12.jpg" width="630" height="130" alt="" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td width="630" height="155" colspan="3" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;" ><p><strong>Nombre de la promoción</strong></p>
        <p>nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nunc.</p>
        <p>Oferta valida desde <strong style="color:#1f52aa">Mar 1 de 2013</strong> hasta <strong style="color:#1f52aa">Junio 10 de 2013</strong></p>
        <p> <del>$1.000.000</del><strong style="color:#1f52aa; font-size:18px"> $800.000</strong></p></td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="654" height="15" colspan="5" bgcolor="#3b64aa"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="654" height="44" colspan="5" bgcolor="#9ba9ce" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">¿Tiene dudas? Preguntas Frecuentes</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="654" height="144" colspan="5" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#000; text-align: justify; vertical-align:top;"><p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nunc.nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nun. nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nun.nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nun</p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="654" height="9" colspan="5" bgcolor="#3b64aa"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="13" height="1"></td>
        <td width="12" height="1"></td>
        <td width="200" height="1"></td>
        <td width="370" height="1"></td>
        <td width="60" height="1"></td>
        <td width="12" height="1"></td>
        <td width="13" height="1"></td>
        <td width="1" height="1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that you have actually comes from the rowspan attributes that you're using.

```
<tr>
    <td width="13" height="900" rowspan="11" bgcolor="#3b64aa">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="654" height="9" colspan="5" bgcolor="#3b64aa"></td>
    <td width="13" height="900" rowspan="11" bgcolor="#3b64aa">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
```

and

```
<tr>
    <td width="12" height="590" rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="630" height="17" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12" height="590" rowspan="5">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
```

both create spaces on either side of middle of your email, with one column of blue and one column of white, for 11 and 5 rows, respectively.

Each Deal that you have listed is two rows of your table, so when you insert a new deal, you add two more rows to the table. You want those two rows to have the same color and spacing around them, so you need to tell the color spacing rows to extend further.

```
<tr>
    <td width="13" height="900" rowspan="13" bgcolor="#3b64aa">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="654" height="9" colspan="5" bgcolor="#3b64aa"></td>
    <td width="13" height="900" rowspan="13" bgcolor="#3b64aa">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
```

and

```
<tr>
    <td width="12" height="590" rowspan="7">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="630" height="17" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="12" height="590" rowspan="7">&nbsp;</td>

</tr>
```

increasing or decreasing the value of the rowspan attribute by 2 for each deal you add or remove.

If you wanted to, you could avoid changing the rowspan every time by putting the deals inside of their own table, in a single row of the larger table. Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>email</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table width="680" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="Table_01">
    <tr>
        <td width="13" height="900" rowspan="8" bgcolor="#3b64aa">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="654" height="9" colspan="5" bgcolor="#3b64aa"></td>
        <td width="13" height="900" rowspan="8" bgcolor="#3b64aa">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="212" height="89" colspan="2" bgcolor="#32322b">
          <img src="images/logo.png" width="212" height="89" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="370" height="89" bgcolor="#32322b" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14pt; color:#FFFFFF; vertical-align:middle; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;" >Deals</td>
        <td width="72" height="89" colspan="2" bgcolor="#32322b">
      <img src="images/cupon.png" width="72" height="89" alt="" /></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="12" height="590" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="630" height="17" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="12" height="590" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>

    <tr> 
    <td colspan="3">
    <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

        <tr>
             <td width="630" height="130" colspan="3">
            <img src ="images/Template-Email-kuponkis_10.jpg" width="630" height="130" alt="" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="630" height="155" colspan="3" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;" ><p><strong>Nombre de la promoción</strong></p>
            <p>nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nunc.</p>
            <p>Oferta valida desde <strong style="color:#1f52aa">Mar 1 de 2013</strong> hasta <strong style="color:#1f52aa">Junio 10 de 2013</strong></p>
            <p> <del>$1.000.000</del><strong style="color:#1f52aa; font-size:18px"> $800.000</strong></p></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="630" height="130" colspan="3">
            <img src="images/Template-Email-kuponkis_12.jpg" width="630" height="130" alt="" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="630" height="155" colspan="3" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000; text-align:left; vertical-align:top;" ><p><strong>Nombre de la promoción</strong></p>
            <p>nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nunc.</p>
            <p>Oferta valida desde <strong style="color:#1f52aa">Mar 1 de 2013</strong> hasta <strong style="color:#1f52aa">Junio 10 de 2013</strong></p>
            <p> <del>$1.000.000</del><strong style="color:#1f52aa; font-size:18px"> $800.000</strong></p></td>

        </tr>

    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td width="654" height="15" colspan="5" bgcolor="#3b64aa"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="654" height="44" colspan="5" bgcolor="#9ba9ce" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#000; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">¿Tiene dudas? Preguntas Frecuentes</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="654" height="144" colspan="5" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#000; text-align: justify; vertical-align:top;"><p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p>nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nunc.nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nun. nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nun.nteger vestibulum dapibus fermentum. Ut vulputate sem a arcu posuere in mollis sem commodo. Donec nunc nunc, pretium ac accumsan eu, vehicula in urna. Nam orci lectus, pellentesque ut laoreet vel, interdum ac nun</p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="654" height="9" colspan="5" bgcolor="#3b64aa"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="13" height="1"></td>
        <td width="12" height="1"></td>
        <td width="200" height="1"></td>
        <td width="370" height="1"></td>
        <td width="60" height="1"></td>
        <td width="12" height="1"></td>
        <td width="13" height="1"></td>
        <td width="1" height="1"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

That way, you can duplicate the deals as may times as you want without changing the rowspan, since they're all only one row tall as far as the enclosing table is concerned.